# Persisting html-control content with runat server tag

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, ajax, user-controls

I have this problem - I'm working on an ASP.NET AJAX-application on a server without .net 3.5 which means I can't use ListView (BOO!).

I decided to simply do the ugly way of making a table and giving the tbody an ID and a runat server tag, and put HtmlControls inside from the codebehind (btw - this is a usercontrol, in case it makes a difference).

This all works fine - until the page does a partial postback - and all the elements disappear, since the tag is runat server I assume it requires to be repopulated in the page load.

Is there no way to actually persist the data on partial postback? And only have the content of the control change when I say so in the back end?

I guess I could save the content in a session object upon populating the control, and just repopulate in the Page_Load with the session object - but I was hoping there was a better way to do this?

Comment: Not sure what you are outputing, but if you want a server control that works in NET 2.0 and outputs as a table then could you use a GridView instead?

Comment: Have you used UpdatePanel? Is your user control in the same update panel from/in which partial postback is occuring?

Comment: I'm an idiot... I should just be using GridView. I've grown to accustomed to ListView, so I completely blacked GridView out :)

Answer (score 0):

You should recreate all controls created dynamically in the Page_Init event and repopulate them in Page_Load. You can refer to this article also https://web.archive.org/web/20210330142645/http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/092904-1.aspx.

Answer (score 0):

If your problem is with saving states.  The `ControlState` is just the right place to do so..

Consider this from msdn (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1whwt1k7.aspx)

or try the following code.

```
    protected override object SaveControlState()
    {
        object[] ControlStateData = new object[];
        //save your data like  ControlStateData[0] = ActivePage;
        return ControlStateData;
    }

    protected override void LoadControlState(object savedState)
    {
        object[] ControlStateData = savedState as object[];
        //Load your data like ActivePage = (int) ControlStateData[0];
        base.LoadControlState(ControlStateData[2]);
    }

    //Dont forget to add this procedure
    protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnInit(e);
        Page.RegisterRequiresControlState(this);
    }
```